# Spliting a page in half horizontally

Tags: minipage

I am trying to fix two half-paged documents on one document, one on top of the other.

The method below works pretty well so far, but I'm having trouble using `0.5\textheight` for the height of the second minipage.  When I change `0.49` to `0.5`, the second page breaks onto another page.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to achieve what I'm looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=0.4in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent = 0.0in

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.5\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
        Page 1
    \end{minipage} \\
    \begin{minipage}[b][0.49\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
        \vspace{0.4in}
        Page 2
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the lines

```
\tracingoutput=1
\showboxdepth=3
\showboxbreadth=99
```

to the preamble and then looking in the log file is instructive. Here is the contents of the main text block:

```
..\vbox(737.15489+0.0)x430.00462, glue set 3.20049fil
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 3.16669
...\hbox(6.83331+361.74413)x430.00462 []
...\penalty 300
...\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
...\hbox(361.20995+0.0)x430.00462 []
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
```

So `\topskip` and lineskip glue are clearly the culprits here.

You can turn off `\topskip` glue for a given page by starting it with

```
\hbox{}\kern-\topskip
```

and you can turn off interlineskip for a given paragraph by ending it with `{\offinterlineskip\par}`.

Comment: Thanks for the trace tips.  Adding `\hbox{}\kern-\topskip` before the beginning of the document seemed to work.

Answer (score 6):

If you wrap the two minipages in a `\vbox` and look at the output, the vbox is overfull by just under 1pt.

The real problem is that the two boxes (that is to say the two `minipage`s) are less than `\lineskiplimit` apart so TeX inserts `\lineskip` glue between them. The way to handle this is to put `\nointerlineskip` before the second `minipage` like this.

```
\vbox{
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.5\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
        Page 1
    \end{minipage}

    \nointerlineskip
    \begin{minipage}[b][0.5\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
        \vspace{0.4in}
        Page 2
    \end{minipage}
}
```

Leaving the `\vbox` there handles the issue with the `\topskip`.

Alternatively, you can remove the `\vbox` and add `\null\kern-\topskip\nointerlineskip` in its place. Again, the `\nointerlineskip` is necessary to keep TeX from trying to put space between the null hbox and the first `minipage`.

Comment: The `\vbox` and `nointerlineskip` method works for me and the `\null\kern-\topskip\nointerlineskip` alternative also works if I add it before the document. Thanks!