# Constant paragraph spacing for questionnaires/surveys in LaTeX

Tags: paragraphs, forms, questionnaire

In order to be able to keep questions hidden until they are answered, I want to fold a survey form (questionnaire) horizonally. Therefore I want to create constant hight paragraphs.

Meaning: independently how large the question text and answer options are, the space down to the next question should remain constant for all questions. As a minimal example you can use this nice [template provided by Sven Hartenstein](https://svenhartenstein.de/creating-questionnaires-with-latex/)

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to split the page into blocks (questions) of the same height. You could have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4243/34936) where a page is split into two horizontally.

Comment: @drat Thank you for the link (-: Somehow it resembles a possible solution, however there the hight is manually set/chosen. I wonder if it would be possible to write the text for the questions and then the template itself decides how large the hight should be to fit every question within.

Comment: do you want the same height for every question in the document or just for every question on a specific page?

Comment: @drat Ideally it would be the same for all pages -- this would allow to fold multiple pages at ones. However, in some scenarios -- e.g. a large question -- it may be more practical to limit the range of the similar hight size only to each page individually. Bottom line: If you know how to do only one variant, I would also accept your answer. Thank you (-: